# Using model arguments for a referenced model with inline parameters

Tags: matlab, parameters, inline, simulink

I am having issues with passing model arguments through referenced models which contain inline parameters.

My Simulink model consists of three ModelReference blocks which refer to the same referenced model (let's call this `subModel`). This `subModel` contains dozens of parameters which should be the same in each instance and a few which I want different for each instance. Currently, within model explorer, the `subModel` workspace is populated using a Matlab script. If I add model arguments within model explorer and then again at the ModelReference block level I get the error:

> 'Model arguments can not be used in non-tunable expressions. The
>   expression '(acc.vRef)^2' in parameter field 'Gain' of
>   'subModel/Force transducer/Gain1' can not be tuned but it
>   refers to variables (acc (model argument))'

So the next logical step is to disable inline parameters, now I get the error:

> 'Model 'subModel' is referenced in Normal Mode and does not
>   have 'Inline parameters' enabled. Go to the Optimization > Signals and
>   Parameters pane of the Configuration Parameters dialog for model
>   'subModel' and enable 'Inline parameters''

So I re-enabled inline parameters and tried creating global tunable parameters from the 'Inline parameters configure' window. This works and I can read in arguments into the subModel this way (as a global tunable parameter), the problem here is I read in the same global arguments into all three referenced subModel instances.

The question in short is, how do I read in model arguments with inline parameters enabled? On another note, this model must also be auto coder compatible.